# Update from mongoose post findOneAndUpdate hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a document for all findOneAndUpdate calls. So I wrote a post hook using the Mongoose Middleware. I am using Mongoose 4.6

```
mySchema.post('findOneAndUpdate', function(result) {
    result.currentEvent = result.Events.slice(-1);
    this.model.update({}, { currentEvent: result.currentEvent }).exec();
});
```

But this only updates the returned object, not the document in my collection. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Mongoose middleware [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) states:

> Query middleware differs from document middleware in a subtle but
>   important way: in document middleware, this refers to the document
>   being updated. In query middleware, mongoose doesn't necessarily have
>   a reference to the document being updated, so this refers to the query
>   object rather than the document being updated.

Try replacing your code with this:

```
mySchema.post('findOneAndUpdate', function(result) {
    result.currentEvent = result.Events.slice(-1);
    this.save(function(err) {
       if(!err) {
         console.log("Document Updated");
        }
     });
});
```

Hopefully, it should work.

You can also find the document and then save the modified document using this code:

```
mySchema.find({*condition*}, function(err, result) {
result.currentEvent = result.Events.slice(-1);
result.save(function (err) {
        if(err) {
        console.error('ERROR!');
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From `mongoose 5.x` and in `Node.js >= 7.6.0:`

```
mySchema.post('findOneAndUpdate', async (result) => {
  result.currentEvent = result.Events.slice(-1);
  await result.save();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using POST Hook Use PRE Hook.

POST Hook: After the collection saved Post Hook will be executed.
PRE Hook: Before saving the collection Pre Hook will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the findOneAndUpdate hook and after you can use the method result.save()

```
mySchema.post('findOneAndUpdate', function(result) {
    result.currentEvent = result.Events.slice(-1);
    result.save(function(err) {
       if(!err) {
         console.log("Document Updated");
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: Multiple duplicate answers. Maybe you can edit your answer to illustrate why it is better than other answers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).